# Foreach nested field not always there

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to ingest the contents of webpages from an array inside of a document

```
{ "myDocument" :  { 
   "author" : "Joe",
   ......
   "linkedPages" : [
       { "name" : "googly",
         "creator" : "SoInSo",
         "url": "http://blah.com/content",
         "pageContent" : "Base64EncodedStuff...."
       },
       ......
    ],
   "tags" : [
   ....
   ]
}
```

And am using an ingest pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information from arrays",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "linkedPages",
        "processor": {
          "attachment": {
            "target_field": "_ingest._value.readableAndSearchable",
            "field": "_ingest._value.pageContent",
            "ignore_failure" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This works fine and even gets around bad data in the pageConent field. Now the problem is that the linkedPages field is optional.  If I send in a document without any linkedPages, Elasticsearch throws an IllegalArgumentException.
I'm setting the ObjectMapper serializationInclustion to Inclusion.NON_NULL which is nicely removing a ton of empty fields from the JSON but leads to the error in this case.

Is there anyway for the Foreach processor to ignore failures?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years late here but as of version 6.4 you are able to specify the `ignore_missing` configuration option for the `foreach` processor like so:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information from arrays",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "foreach": {
        "field": "linkedPages",
        "processor": {
          "attachment": {
            "target_field": "_ingest._value.readableAndSearchable",
            "field": "_ingest._value.pageContent",
            "ignore_failure" : true
          }
        },
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This approach should avoid the error you were experiencing by skipping all cases that the `linkedPages` field isn't specified.

If instead you want the failure to happen, but would like to ignore it you can specify the `ignore_failure` option on the `foreach` processor as of version 6.5.

Furthermore, if you would like to allow the failure but handle the error as a part of the pipeline you can specify an array of processors in the `on_failure` config option (also available as of 6.5).

Relevant docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/foreach-processor.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/handling-failure-in-pipelines.html